# Filtering listbox based on textbox text in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, filtering

I was wondering if I could get some help with this one.

I'm using a dataset containing 2 tables (dbo.Project, and dbo.Materials) and collectionview to display data into a listbox.
I need to filter the dataset by materials used in the project through the use of two textboxes and returns the project names into the listbox. So far I have it to where it loads and my listbox populates with the list of projects properly, but the textboxes are not filtering.

Any suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have so far is:

```
Imports System.Windows.Data
Imports System.Windows

Public Class SearchMe
    Private mds As New MaterialsDataSet
    Private pta As New MaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.ProjectTableAdapter
    Private mta As New MaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.MaterialsTableAdapter
    Private tam As New MaterialsDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager
    Private view As CollectionView

    Private Sub SearchMe_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Me.tam.ProjectTableAdapter = pta
        Me.tam.MaterialsTableAdapter = mta

        Me.pta.Fill(Me.mds.Project)
        Me.mta.Fill(Me.mds.Materials)

        Me.DataContext = Me.mds.Project
        Me.view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Me.mds.Project)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        If Material2.Text.Length > 0 Then
            Dim query = From p In mds.Project
                        Join m In mds.Materials On p.ProjectID Equals m.ProjectID
                        Where m.Material = Me.Material2.Text.ToString
                        Select p
        Else
            Dim query = From p In mds.Project
                        Join m In mds.Materials On p.ProjectID Equals m.ProjectID
                        Where m.Material = Me.Material1.Text
                        Select p.ProjectName

            Me.DataContext = query
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        Me.DataContext = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub Material1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles Material1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Material2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles Material2.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SearchMe"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="SearchMe" Height="500" Width="750" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False" ShowActivated="False" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,45,46,60" Name="MyLists" Width="346" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="#FF860909"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   
             DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName"/>
    <Button Content="Search" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="403,417,0,0" Name="btnSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Reset" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="556,417,0,0" Name="btnReset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <TextBox Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,87,0,0" Name="Material1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="269" />
    <TextBox Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,192,0,0" Name="Material2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="269" />
</Grid>
```

Any and all input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this worked for me... Under the btn_Search Click event:

```
Dim query = From p In mds.Project
                Join m In mds.Materials On p.ProjectID Equals m.ProjectID
                Where m.Materia.ToLower().Contain(m.Material1.Text())
                Select new with {.ProjectName = p.ProjectName}
```

Hope this helps anyone out.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many potential problems here, and I haven't had the time to go through your code in detail. But you could try to call the Refresh method on "Me.view" after replacing the DataContext in the click event.